# Как можно поменять стиль только выделенной строки?

Tags: java

Добрый день! Пытаюсь сделать изменение шрифта, стиля (border, italic), размера шрифта для выделенной строки из `JTextArea`. Изменение стиля регулируются выпадающими списками. Пока получилось реализовать изменение стиля и шрифта всего текста из `JTextArea` с помощью `StyledDocument`. Для выделенной строки я подумал что при изменении стиля или размера шрифта в выпадающих списках то необходимо получить подстроку без выделенной строки, вставить обратно в `JTextArea` и потом с помощью метода `insertString()` вставить выделенную строку уже с указаным стилем и шрифтом. Может кто знает способ по проще?

```
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie) { 
    String selectedText = textarea.getSelectedText();
    String text = textarea.getText();
    style = styles.getSelectedItem();
    size = Integer.parseInt(sizes.getSelectedItem());

    if (selectedText == null) {

        try {
            styledDoc.remove(0, styledDoc.getLength());
            styledDoc.insertString(0, text, 
                      styledDoc.getStyle(ie.getItem().toString()));                
        } catch (BadLocationException b) { 
            System.out.println(b.getMessage());
        }
    } 
    else { 
        int posSelectedText = text.indexOf(selectedText);
        String bufString1 = text.substring(0, posSelectedText-1);
        String bufString2 = text.substring(posSelectedText 
                            + selectedText.length());
        textarea.setText(bufString1 + bufString2);

        try {
            bp.doc.insertString(posSelectedText-1, selectedText, 
                                styledDoc.getStyle(style));
        } catch (BadLocationException b) { 
            System.out.println(b.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replaceSelection(String content)

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html

Comment: Хммм... Не заметил данный метод. Спасибо!